# Trigger PHP script through NodeJs

Tags: php, node.js

I want to run a PHP script through NodeJs. URL for PHP function is like "http://www.mydomain/test.php/myfunction".
Is there a way I can trigger that URL like we did using Curl/AJAX? Please help me I didn't find any solution yet. 
Thanks.

Comment: If your function outputs json data as a response then you can use it in your nodejs app. You can send a GET or POST from your node app and in PHP set the header to JSON.